# Excel Macro to Search for Key Words in a list and return a value for matches

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a macro that can search a worksheet or multiple worksheets for keywords that are contained in a word list within the document and returns a value for each corresponding keyword.

E.g.

List
1. Happy
2. Sad
3. Melancholy

The macro would return either '1' in column B, for example, if the cell in column A said "I'm really happy about my training." This would be use to categorize open-ended responses in questionnaries.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. I have found using formulas too cumbersome and time consuming. I believe a macro would be quicker and more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
        a = r.Value
        If InStr(1, a, "Happy") > 0 Then r.Offset(0, 1) = 1
        If InStr(1, a, "Sad") > 0 Then r.Offset(0, 1) = 2
        If InStr(1, a, "Melancholy") > 0 Then r.Offset(0, 1) = 3
    Next r
End Sub
```

Please note....it will match Happy.  It will not match happy.